# Pointer and allocation outside function or static variable and allocation inside?

Tags: c, pointers, static

Don't freak out about the length of my post, it's pretty simple, I just don't know how to put it any shorter:

I have two ways of doing something pretty much similar to merging two arrays via a function. Here I call the function `combine_data()`. The arrays are called `data1` and `data2`. Suppose my arrays are like:

```
int num1 = 4;
int num2 = 6;

double data1[num1] = /* some values */
double data2[mum2] = /* some values */
```

## Solution 1

I can either use a solution I find more elegant but I'm unsure if it's good practice and will behave properly. <s>The solution relies on a static variable intended to make the array persistent</s>. Somehow that feels like it could blow up in my face some way.

```
// SOLUTION 1
double* combine_data(
    const int num1, const double* const data1,
    const int num2, const double* const data2
) {
    int i;
    int num = num1 + num2;
    double *combi;   // static because the data stored the should persist
    combi = (double*)malloc( num*sizeof(*combi) );
    /* some code */
    for(i=0; i<num1; ++i)   combi[i] = data[i];
    for(i=num1; i<num; ++i) combi[i] = data[i];

    return combi;
}

double *combi = combine_data(num1, data1, num2, data2);
/* some code */
free(combi);    // problem with free of a static variable in combine_data() ???
```

## Solution 2

Or I could use the approach I'm more used to, that uses pointers for the same functionality:

```
// SOLUTION 2
void combine_data(
    const int num1, const double* const data1,
    const int num2, const double* const data2
    double* combi
) {
    /* some code */
    for(i=0; i<num1; ++i)   combi[i] = data[i];
    for(i=num1; i<num; ++i) combi[i] = data[i];
}

int num = num1 + num2;
double *combi = (double*)malloc( num*sizeof(combi) );
combine_data(num1, data1, num2, data2, combi);
/* some code */
free(combi);
```

Solution 2 has the problem that nothing prevents the user from this: `combine_data(num1, data1, num2, data2, data1)`, which would screw up `data1`. Solution 2 hides the allocation, and is easier to use, which I find more elegant, but I don't know how it will behave especially when freeing the memory. **Which solution is the best and why?**

Also btw. is there a difference between the two?:

```
const int* const name
const int const *name
```

**Edit:** One really is a syntax error i've seen in faulty code and wondered. Also discarded the `static`.

Comment: why do you need the static pointer in solution 1? Why not just return a pointer to allocated memory and let the caller free it?

Comment: `double *combi = (double*)malloc( num*sizeof(combi) );` works coincidentally because you have a 64-bits operating system and pointers are the same size as `double`s. `sizeof(combi)` is the same as `sizeof(double*)`; what you really need is `sizeof(*combi)`.

Comment: @zbeak Yes I know. I just mistyped but thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you need to make `combi` static in solution 1? The pointer does not have to persist, only what is pointed to by it. The pointer is then returned by value, so no memory leak occurs.

Which solution you choose depends solely on your assumption as to the style of the whole program. You have to decide whether the function should allocate and return a pointer to allocated memory, or accept a pointer to already allocated memory.

Both solutions are correct, and in my opinion equally good. In solution 2 you may also check for equality between input and output pointers and return an error code. You can even check for memory overlapping, not only pointer equality. But then again, it all depends on what responsibilities you assign to different parts of your program.

Comment: Ährm yeah. I thought `staic double *name` would make the data it points to static and `double* static name` the pointer just like `const` would make them constant.

Comment: No, `static` in a function refers to variables on stack (locals), and the memory it points to may be anything, that's why you don't have to (and even shouldn't) use it in this case. Note also, that const in `double const * name` will not make the memory constant, it only won't allow you to change it through this pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Your second solution is better. Static variables are going to kill you would you ever go multithreaded.

As of prventing the user from using your function wrong, you can assert that `data1+num1` and `data2+num2` don't overlap.

There is a difference between `const int* const name` and `const int* name`. The latter means you can't change the values pointed by `name` but you can assign `name` itself to another pointer, the former means you can't change the values nor the pointer.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thanks. I'm positive that I will never go multithreaded.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a difference between const int* const name and const int
>   const *name

Yes, the second is a syntax error.

As to which of the solutions is better... Well, I don't think that the problem that you're afraid in solution 2 isn't present in solution 1. You *do* return `combi` in the first solution, so the user can save it and then pass it again to the same function which would *screw* things up as well. So, my vote goes for second solution. (by the way, you could check in the function that neither `data1` nor `data2` are equal to `combi`)

Answer (score 1):

The second solution has the advantage that you can pass it arrays of different storage classes. Global array, stack allocated (VLA) or heap allocated. This gives you more flexibility which might come handy if your function is used by different parts of a big project (imagine a library).

```
double combi[num1+num2];
combine_data(num1, data1, num2, data2, combi);
/* some code */
/*forget free(combi) it's not necessary anymore;
```

EDIT: Besides, the advantage of making the allocation in the caller instead of the callee can have also impact on the algorithmic complexity of the solution. If we imagine that your combine function is called in a loop. With the first solution you will have a lot of copies.

1st solution

```
 data1, data2, data3, data4
 comb1 = combine_data(len1, data1, len2, data2);
 comb2 = combine_data(len3, data3, len4, data4);
 comb3 = combine_data(len1+len2, comb1, len3+len4, comb2);
 /* ... */
 free(comb1); 
 free(comb2); 
 free(comb3);
```

2nd solution

```
 data1, data2, data3, data4
 comb = malloc(len1+len2+len3+len4);
 combine_data(len1, data1, len2, data2, comb);
 combine_data(len3, data3, len4, data2, comb+len1+len2);     /* This case can of course only be used because we know what combine does */

 /* ... */
 free(comb);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm tending more and more towards solution #2. Hiding the allocation has the other disadvantage, that it is easier to forget to free `combi` than if the user has allocated it himself.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` in the first solution serves no purpose, you can remove it and the function will function identical (except that it is threadsafe).